# How to distinguish the Android, Win7 user agents in C#

Tags: c#, browser

I used the following code to distinguish whether it is Android device when they access my website.

```
public static bool IsAndroid()
{
    string userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request
                       .UserAgent.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    if (userAgent.Contains("android"))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

But, now I want to check it not only Android but also check it is Win 7. So what should I do?

Comment: Generally, you should access your server with a Win 7 pad and see what UserAgent is in the headers (using either a sniffer like fiddler / wireshark, or by checking your IIS server logs). Hopefully it has a unique footprint, which you can then filter on. I don't think it has, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser property. The framework has the capability to analyze the user-agent header based on several profiles located in %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Config\Browsers.

As Paul-Jan mentioned you'd probably access your server with your devices and extend those profiles. Maybe you can use statistics from Akamai for example to identify common user-agent headers, but I'm not sure if they provide those informations.

See also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx